# Is there a way for me to insert a regex so that python unittest will run certain tests in all the test files matching that regular expression?

Tags: python, python-unittest

So currently my testing folder is divided into directories that contain all the test files IE: test1.py, test2.py etc etc. Each of the testing files contain a certain amount of test methods. Is it possible for me to insert a regular expression so that python unittest will look through ALL the python files and only run those test methods that  match the regular expression? I know that python unittest can do this for running all the tests for files that match the regular expression, but I want to run all the METHODS that match the regular expressions by looking through all the files. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you regroup those special tests in a specific file/folder and run unittest on it ?

If it doesn't suit you, I think you could use the skip (and skipIf, skipUnless and the whole family)decorators as a substitute.